# One eCommerce Store using multiple PayPal accounts

Tags: api, e-commerce, paypal

I was wondering if someone knew of a way to theoretically have one eCommerce store to act as a medium where sellers can sign up and sell goods and use their PayPal account to receive payments instead?

So, Vendor A signs up, stores their PayPal information. Whenever a customer purchases items form Vendor A, the money goes straight to Vendor A's PayPal account rather than the eCommerce store acting as a middleman and later has to payout all the vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds possible to me, as long as you have the vendor's paypal information, however that would make your data a security risk, because you would have to store the paypal information for multiple vendors.